# Showing Fourier modes tend to 0 arbitrarily slowly for continous functions

Tags: proof-writing, fourier-analysis

I'm asked to prove that for a given sequence $ \{\beta_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ with $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \beta_{k} = 0, \exists g \in C(\mathbb{T})$ such that $ \lim\sup_{k\to\infty} \frac{|\hat{g}(k)|}{\beta_{k}} \ge 1 $

Note $ \mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R} \backslash 2\pi \mathbb{Z} $

I'm not too sure how to start. What I've done so far is to use the fact that for $ f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{T})$

$ |\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(x) e^{-i \pi k} dx| \le \frac{1}{2 \pi} ||f||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{T})} $

But as this inequality is the wrong way around I don't think this is the correct direction to go in...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider a solution of the form
$$g(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} c_k\exp(i\pi k)$$

You need to ensure:

- the series makes sense and $c_k=\hat g(k)$ (e.g. $\sum |c_k|<\infty$)
- $g$ is continuous (e.g. $\sum |c_k|<\infty$)
- $\limsup_{k\to\infty} |c_k/\beta_k|=1$ (e.g. $c_k=\beta_k$ for infinitely many $k$)

If you can arrange these properties to hold, you're done.

Comment: are the $ c_{k} $ fourier coefficents? Also what do you mean by Fourier modes?

if we are considering functions in $ L^{1} $ then can't we say that the $ c_{k}$ will be bounded if it's in $ L^{1}$ (we don't need to consider $ exp(i \pi k) $ since this has norm of 1).

Comment: @TKD: yeah $c_k$ are coefficients not modes, fixed. You get to choose $c_k,$ so you get to choose whether they're bounded or not.